# Get time split into minutes and seconds

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, which is supposed to do what I need:

```
function fromSeconds(seconds, showHours = false) {
    if(showHours) {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600),
            seconds = seconds - hours * 3600;
    }
    var minutes = (Math.floor(seconds/60) < 10) ? 
        "0" + Math.floor(seconds/60) : Math.floor(seconds/60);
    var seconds = (seconds % 60 > 9) ? seconds % 60 : "0" + seconds % 60;

    if(showHours) {
        var timestring = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
        var timestring = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
    return timestring;
}
```

The problems is that I also have this:

```
var video = $('#home_explainer_placeholder');
video.bind("timeupdate", function() {
    $('#currentTime').html(video[0].currentTime.toFixed(2));
    $('#remTime').html((video[0].duration - video[0].currentTime).toFixed(2));
    $('#totalTime').html(video[0].duration.toFixed(2));
});
```

And I don't know how to apply the first code so that for example `currentTime` is displayed like this: `minutes:seconds`.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a small fixation you can leave this as that:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pg8akkmj/1/)

```
function fromSeconds(seconds, showHours) {
    if(showHours) {
        var hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600),
            seconds = seconds - hours * 3600;
    }
    var minutes = ("0" + Math.floor(seconds/60)).slice(-2);
    var seconds = ("0" + parseInt(seconds%60,10)).slice(-2);

    if(showHours) {
        var timestring = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    } else {
        var timestring = minutes + ":" + seconds;
    }
    return timestring;
}

var video = $('#home_explainer_placeholder');
video.bind("timeupdate", function () {
    $('#currentTime').html(fromSeconds(video[0].currentTime));
    $('#remTime').html(fromSeconds(video[0].duration - video[0].currentTime));
    $('#totalTime').html(fromSeconds(video[0].duration));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the values like `video[0].currentTime` to the function `fromSeconds` which will return the formatted string

```
var video = $('#home_explainer_placeholder');
video.bind("timeupdate", function () {
    $('#currentTime').html(fromSeconds(video[0].currentTime));
    $('#remTime').html(fromSeconds(video[0].duration - video[0].currentTime));
    $('#totalTime').html(fromSeconds(video[0].duration));
});
```

Comment: Your answer also worked, with a simple addition: it was showing me the miliseconds. Thanks a lot. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#currentTime').html(function(){
     var time=video[0].currentTime.toFixed(2);
     //some conversion needed in-order to convert to required format
     fromSeconds(time,false)//returns time 
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will also verify this.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `currentTime` is the time in seconds, you need to pass the value into your function.

`fromSeconds` returns the text your require, so `fromSeconds(mytimevalue)` will return `mm:ss` as required:

```
video.bind("timeupdate", function() {
    $('#currentTime').html( fromSeconds(video[0].currentTime) );
    $('#remTime').html( fromSeconds(video[0].duration - video[0].currentTime) );
    $('#totalTime').html( fromSeconds(video[0].duration) );
});
```

Another option would be to use JavaScript's `Date()` Object, which takes milliseconds as a value:
`var currentTime = new Date(video[0].currentTime * 1000);`

You can then use `Date.getMinutes()` and `Date.getSeconds()` to find your values.

More details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Thank you for this. I will also verify this. +1